# How can I get a location point on a country depend on Android phone configuration

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I'm develop a android app with Google Map. In app start, if user don't turn on Location Service (can't get user current location, right ?),

I want my map zoom to current user's country base on configuration of phone . How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, of course, you can use user's system language to guess their location.. but you know, everyone in the US probably has the same language.

If you can not use GPS, the next best thing to do is to determine users' location by some sort of IP address locator. Even google maps provided their own IP to location services, but they have not updated it for a while. Please also look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870879/how-to-get-the-client-user-location-details/30873020#30873020) for more information.

You should consider using some kind of APIs like this one
http://www.telize.com/

> GeoIP (Get IP address location in JSON format) :
>
> Calling the API endpoint without any parameter will return location information for the visitor IP address :
>
> Example (JSON) : http://www.telize.com/geoip
>
> ```
> {"longitude":-97,"latitude":38,"asn":"AS15169","ip":"xxxx:x:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx",
> "area_code":"0","continent_code":"NA","dma_code":"0","country_code":"US",
> "isp":"Google Inc.","country":"United States","country_code3":"USA"}
> ```